# How to make an instance method accept only the name of another instance method?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object with some properties and methods. How do I give it a method that accepts only the name of another one of its methods?

For example, consider the `command` method in this `User` class. We want `command` to accept the name of another method. Using `keyof this` narrows the acceptable type to `User` property names; how would we narrow it further to just `User` *method* names, without hardcoding them?

```
class User {
    nameFirst: string;
    nameLast: string;

    command(commandName: keyof this) {
        this[commandName].call(this);
    }

    sink() {}

    swim() {}
}

const alice = new User();
alice.command(`swim`); // Accepts `nameFirst` | `nameLast` | `command` | `sink` | `swim`; we want it to accept only `sink` and `swim`
```

Comment: You probably *should* hardcode them, as e.g. it does not make sense to call `command("command")` or `command("constructor")`

Comment: Have you considered decomposition, like `interface UserCommands`, `class User implements UserCommands` and `(commandName: keyof UserCommands)`?

Answer (score 1):

To narrow the acceptable types of the command method to only User method names without hardcoding them, you can combine conditional and mapped types.

```js
type FunctionPropertyNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

class User {
  nameFirst: string;
  nameLast: string;

  command(commandName: FunctionPropertyNames<User>) {
    this[commandName].call(this);
  }

  sink() {
    console.log('Sink');
  }

  swim() {
    console.log('Swim');
  }
}

const alice = new User();
alice.command('swim'); // This is now restricted to 'sink' and 'swim'
```

Comment: "This is now restricted to 'sink' and 'swim'" Not quite, it also allows `"command"`

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript doesn't have a built-in `KeysMatching<T, V>` type operator to extract the keys of a type `T` whose values match a certain other type `V`, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992), but you can implement one yourself that works for some use cases, for example:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> =
  { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T]
```

Then conceptually you'd make `commandName` of type `KeysMatching<User, ()=>void>` so that it only allows zero-arg methods.  But this will cause a circularity warning (since the type of `commandName` depends on the type of `User` which depends on the type of `command` which depends on the type of `commandName`).  You can circumvent this by omitting `"command"` from the keys to allow, using [the `Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys):

```
class User {
  nameFirst: string = "";
  nameLast: string = "";

  command(commandName: KeysMatching<Omit<User, "command">, () => void>) {
    this[commandName].call(this);
  }

  sink() { }

  swim() { }

  needsParam(x: string) { console.log(x.toUpperCase()) }
}

const alice = new User();
alice.command("swim")
alice.command("sink");
alice.command("nameFirst"); // error, not accepted
alice.command("needsParam"); // error, not accepted
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAaRhAzgWQIZgMYAsCWAdgOYA8AKgDRwBqAfHALyhxwDecA2gnEXANbIA9gDM45ALoAucdwlwYADzAxCAExS04AfkRwZhGADcYAJzgBfToIijxE0KGwAbDCk0BVFGfYs4hDABbGAAxfFMUMBlI0yJiJjgAIkSAbj8A4IAZNyi4GLiE5LSQP2whQMCMdQAKMoqqtQA5IJgZJFRMHAISUgB5QPwwUi8zakS6yvVEumpqgEomBiMhfDU6BbY-VjACFE4JhubgiQA6bAxnZ2qd-BQ54tYLRxBWFCJ+efZLZ9eAd3xAp8OE8Si9-DAYBoAAoYUxBaqKaJgWIkDZwMqEFBCZwwE7OITEBEnMBCDxQWCmADCbhg8wWIJBTiEmLAcAu+Gw8EY4N+cBGpnmxXZnLO5UmamqiRQ-0CiTmoGFuIONSl7zlQucHKVYoakoyoXCkXVcAA9CaFKZTEJTNRCEJWRhsJyoCo1ArNSLlRLEoZISgYXDZfdTeazFabf57WynTAXZDns8gA)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do specifically but could this work for your use case?

```
class User {
    nameFirst: string;
    nameLast: string;

    command(commandName: keyof this) {
      if (typeof this[commandName] === 'function') {
            this[commandName].call(this);
      } 
      else {
        return
      }
    }

    sink() {}

    swim() {}
}

const alice = new User();
alice.command(`swim`);
```