# How to type an instance method of a derived class so that it calls another instance method?

Tags: typescript

We have a base class, and then some derived classes that extend the base class.

We want to define an instance method that is strongly-typed such that it accepts only the name of another instance method.

Since we want all of the derived classes to have this method, we defined it on the base class. But we can't figure out how to type it correctly.

Here's the best we've come up with, using `keyof this`:

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract species: string;

    breathe() {
        console.log(`Ahh`);
    }

    exec(methodName: keyof this) {
        (this[methodName] as () => void)();
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    lovesCatnip = true;
    species = `felis catus`;

    meow() {
        console.log(`Meow`);
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    chasesCars = true;
    species = `canis familiaris`;

    bark() {
        console.log(`Woof`);
    }
}

const fido = new Dog();
fido.exec(`breathe`); // Good
fido.exec(`bark`); // Good
fido.exec(`species`); // Bad
fido.exec(`chasesCars`); // Bad
const snowball = new Cat();
snowball.exec(`breathe`); // Good
snowball.exec(`meow`); // Good
snowball.exec(`species`); // Bad
snowball.exec(`lovesCatnip`); // Bad
```

Note the comments; because `exec` uses `keyof this` it accepts any instance property, whereas we want it to accept only instance methods.

[We asked a similar question previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77498197/how-to-make-an-instance-method-accept-only-the-name-of-another-instance-method), and the answer works when `exec` is defined on the same class as the methods that we want to call, but not when `exec` is defined on a super class.

How do we type `exec` so that when it's called on a derived class it accepts only the names of instance methods on the derived class?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOr7rW) meet your needs?   There's also [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLrEAw) which is easier for callers but still needs a type assertion.  Or possibly [the combined approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1QbGw).  If any of those works for you, let me know and I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: The second approach with `KeysMatching` works great! If you post it as an answer I'll mark it 'accepted'. Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz Actually, it's not quite working as expected. I'll post an update.

Comment: I'm not really prepared to deal with scope changes that occur as a result of my  suggestions, especially when my suggestion is then incorporated into the question.  In my experience, such goalpost shifting only ends when I give up entirely.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm happy to accept your answer and post the updated question separately.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry.  I expect the followup question will require you to widen `this` to the class instance type at the call site, or a type assertion or something.  I'll work on the answer to this question for now.

Comment: Oh, no problem! I appreciate you taking the time to explain — I find Typescript fascinating and really want to understand how these types fit together. `this` in JavaScript is already hard to grok; `this` in Typescript types is even more-so! Here's the follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77572644/2053389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't have a native utility type `KeysMatching<T, V>` which produces the subset of `keyof T` such that the properties at those keys are known to match `V` (so that `T[KeysMatching<T, V>] extends V`).  There is an open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992). It is possible for users to work around the missing feature and implement their own `KeysMatching<T, V>` utility types, which work for some use cases.  Here is one:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> =
  { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T]
```

This is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the properties of `T` into which we immediately [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of its property value types.  In this case the property value type is the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) `T[K] extends V ? K : never`, so this turns into the union of all keys `K` such that `T[K] extends V`.

Let's test it out:

```
class Test {
  foo: string = "";
  bar() { };
  baz = (x?: string) => x?.toUpperCase()
}
type TestKeys = KeysMatching<Test, () => void>;
// type TestKeys = "bar" | "baz"
```

Looks good: you get the keys of `Test` which are assignable to `()=>void`, meaning they can be called as a zero-arg function.  This includes `"bar"` (a zero-arg class method) and `"baz"` (a function-valued property whose argument is optional), but not `"foo"` (a `string`).

---

Conceptually then all you'd need to do is

```
abstract class Animal {
  abstract species: string;

  breathe() {
    console.log(`Ahh`);
  }

  exec(methodName: KeysMatching<this, () => void>) { // uh oh
    this[methodName](); // error
  }
}
```

but there are a few problems.  The biggest one is that this definition is circular; the compiler will try to figure out whether you can call `animal.exec("exec")` and get hopelessly confused.  This can be worked around in a number of ways; let's use [the `Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) to avoid that:

```
abstract class Animal {
  abstract species: string;

  breathe() {
    console.log(`Ahh`);
  }

  exec(methodName: KeysMatching<Omit<this, "exec">, () => void>) {
    this[methodName](); // error
  }
}
```

The next issue is that `this[methodName]()` is considered an error.  That's because, even though the above implementation `KeysMatching<T, V>` works for some use cases, the compiler doesn't "understand" what it does.  While it might be able to verify `T[KeysMatching<T, V>] extends V` for individual specific instantiations of `T` and `V`, it doesn't understand it [generically](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the abstract.  The type of `this[methodName]` inside the body of `exec()` is `this[KeysMatching<Omit<this, "exec">, ()=>void]`; and since the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) is implicitly generic with the current class as a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), the compiler cannot verify that this type must extend `()=>void`.  So it complains.

The easiest fix to that is just to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) as you've already done:

```
abstract class Animal {
  abstract species: string;

  breathe() {
    console.log(`Ahh`);
  }

  exec(methodName: KeysMatching<Omit<this, "exec">, () => void>) {
    (this[methodName] as () => void)();
  }
}
```

There are further things you could do with [`this` parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) and generics to try to get slightly better behavior in the body of `exec()`, but I won't digress to discuss them here.

---

Anyway, let's test it out:

```
const fido = new Dog();
fido.exec(`breathe`); // okay
fido.exec(`bark`); // okay
fido.exec(`species`); // error!
fido.exec(`chasesCars`); // error!
const snowball = new Cat();
snowball.exec(`breathe`); // okay
snowball.exec(`meow`); // okay
snowball.exec(`species`); // error!
snowball.exec(`lovesCatnip`); // error!
```

Looks good.  It accepts correct inputs and rejects incorrect ones. Also, my IDE autosuggests the entries of `KeysMatching<Dog, ()=>void>` and `KeysMatching<Cat, ()=>void>` when I write `fido.exec(⋯` and `snowball.exec(⋯`, respectively, so developers should be able to have a reasonable user experience at the call site.

---

Well, a good call site experience as long as the object you're calling `exec()` on is of a specific known type like `Cat` and `Dog`.  If it is on a generic type like `T extends Animal` or the polymorphic `this` type (which behaves like `T extends Animal` if `this` is of type `Animal`), then the compiler will fail to see what `KeysMatching<T, V>` "means" and you'll get errors:

```
function oops<T extends Dog>(dog: T) {
  dog.exec("bark"); // error
}
class Ugh extends Dog {
  foo() { this.exec("bark") }; // error
}
```

Possibly, someday, microsoft/TypeScript#48992 will be implemented, and then these problems will all disappear because `this[KeysMatching<this, ()=>void>]` and `T[KeysMatching<T, ()=>void>]` will automatically be seen as constrained to `()=>void`.  But for now, you might have to deal with some rough spots.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcCyBDYBjAFgSwHYHMAeAFQBooA1APigF4AoKKAbygG0Yo8oBreAewBmUYgF0AXCI6ioEAB7AIuACYJKUAPywok3BABuEAE5QAvmz4ghI0fXroANigRriEBMBaMog-v0keRnj4dFAARGEA3N4ARihGABQAlCxm0UxxAF6hCXIaAcBBBCm0NHkAdMD8AKpgkEYAws4QyfSm9KCQIu7AcIihfchoWMEkPeTJdDT6-NjKVNEA9ItQndBuHoOhYXFGYVAAPuFZYXYoMYEo6J6OzmoAgrjYALYoDl5M55fXUAiQ6Nh3AUivhorEjBA0JgWilmN4mOh+LgEPwHBByg5+PgEgADe6YTA4pLpMx2JjyCDoBLPCDATD8ZQAORQNMkg1QGBwBEIAHlnthgIQ6dgEOQwhT0GEqBMStNZvNYfCoAlhQg2DS6QzmTSZM5lbKoDM5klkiT2u17E4XFAmp55IoVA8nq93nCmJjDAhbU8wKFCgBXCAkv6UwFqWhQHGCCAOEVQdBof0IHFgpg0-gAd0mbqY8aRKLRGKxuKQEEzRLNbTst2tABEsbIFEpVFBHi83h945hml74uHVkZA8H-mHQjiE081IIWdhY-ERSmyVBdjxs0rEcjUejMdicQB1PyCCvec3V-OeQRzfihPQZqD17HE+iX5T8coS3ExCFQiAVqDLKB+B4FAQGfK93zkSlP3iHg-wAoCQLA18IKgnEQwBdw4JWYwjH4IwAEIkLfD9x27BB3CaIxk2Jf9sKMXCCPsc9flwTM4gcd4I1vG00FNegEFYjN2IcFCqRxL9ITpX8aPg4DQIEti3hEkj0wzLDALk-jBOE0TcXQsN1JwvDCIUoSlN0nEPQotAfUM+jjLsQR-Vwa5sCRQD+DABASEbB0WwfKgElffBJGIRUmGC3SdhgsIZLohiqxrNRqnwTBfObNQH07Xx+GzVYcAQKKV1itJaNkeyjDaIA)