# How to call an instance method that calls another instance method, while preserving the instance type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

We have a base class, and then some derived classes that extend the base class. We want to define an instance method that is strongly-typed such that it accepts only the name of another instance method.

Since we want all of the derived classes to have this method, we defined it on the base class. But we can't figure out how to type it correctly.

So far we have the desired result when calling the method from *outside* the instance, but not when calling it from *inside* the instance with `this`. For example:

```
type KeysMatching<Type, Value> = { // https://stackoverflow.com/q/77571882/2053389
    [Key in keyof Type]: Type[Key] extends Value ? Key : never
}[keyof Type];

abstract class Animal {
    abstract species: string;
    
    breathe() {
        console.log(`Ahh`);
    }
    
    exec<K extends KeysMatching<this, () => void>>(methodName: K) {
        (this[methodName] as () => void)();
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    chasesCars = true;
    species = `canis familiaris`;
    
    bark() {
        console.log(`Woof`);
    }
}

const fido = new Dog();
fido.exec(`breathe`); // Good: no error
fido.exec(`bark`); // Good: no error
fido.exec(`species`); // Good: type error
fido.exec(`chasesCars`); // Good: type error

class Cat extends Animal {
    lovesCatnip = true;
    species = `felis catus`;
    
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.exec(`meow`); // Bad: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'KeysMatching<this, () => void>'
    }
    
    meow() {
        console.log(`Meow`);
    }
}

const snowball = new Cat();
snowball.exec(`breathe`); // Good: no error
snowball.exec(`meow`); // Good: no error
snowball.exec(`species`); // Good: type error
snowball.exec(`lovesCatnip`); // Good: type error
```

How can we set up `exec` so that it can be called as `this.exec` and `instance.exec` with the correct typing?

Comment: Generic param kinda gross https://tsplay.dev/WJrDkW

Comment: @katniss That's interesting! I didn't expect a class to accept itself as a generic. Would love to hear an explanation of why it has to be that way?

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be that way, but it's one way to work around it; the issue is as I describe at the bottom of my answer to another question; `this` behaves as a generic type parameter and thus `KeysMatching<this, XXX>` is opaque to the compiler.  If you write `KeysMatching<Cat, XXX>`, it will work fine.  The recursive generic `class Cat extends Animal<Cat> {}` is a way of simulating `this` without having it stay generic inside the subclass.

Comment: (see prev comment)  Another workaround is to explicitly widen `this` to `Cat` before calling `exec()`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w2QA8W).  I don't know if there's an approach that doesn't require subclass implementations to do something "weird", so I'm not sure if either of these are approaches you're interested in.